# Android: Create bigger Floating Action Button with bigger icon

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to create a bigger Floating Action Button (FAB), more than the usual 56 dp, with a bigger icon inside.
(For my purpose an icon will never be self-explanatory so I will create a png-file containing a short text and use this png as icon.)

Increasing the size of the FAB works fine:
as i don't use the mini-FloatingActionButton, i redefined the mini-button-size.
in my **layout-xml** i specify:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    app:fabSize="mini"
    ....
```

and in the **dimensions.xml** i redefine the size for the mini-fab:

```
<dimen name="fab_size_mini">80dp</dimen>
```

However, I didn't manage to get a bigger icon on the FAB.
I tried icons with different dp's from the material icons library - no success. Also setting a padding on the FAB-layout did not work.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: For custom size w/out custom image - can set `scaleX`, `scaleY` -https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637787/2162226

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try to redefine the maximum size of the fab image size in your `dimensions.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_fab_size_mini" tools:override="true">80dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_fab_content_size" tools:override="true">48dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Must make sure you override the original resources in the Design Library. Try `design_fab_image_size` instead of `design_fab_content_size` if this does not work for you.

Use with care as this is a hack not an actual solution. Solution might not work if the resource's name is changed in the future Design Library release. My opinion is to stick with the size that is define in the Design Library as it is the recommended design guideline based on the Material Design which make your overall app looks good.

Comment: thanks Grace Coder. for me it works perfectly if i write "fab_size_mini" instead of "design_fab_size_mini" and "fab_content_size" instead of "design_fab_content_size".

Comment: Great answer. fab_size_mini and fab_size_normal works

Comment: Superb answer @Grace Coder

Comment: If anybody wonders, you can find the dimen names here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/res/values/dimens.xml, looks like it is indeed `design_fab_image_size`

Comment: Works perfectly in my case as I have to customise for a single device

Comment: why do not you do it like this in XML android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"

Answer (score 20):

For changing the fab size use

```
app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
```

And for the icon size

```
app:maxImageSize="50dp"
```

Example

```
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_start"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
            app:fabCustomSize="70dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:maxImageSize="40dp"
            app:tint="@color/white_overlay_1"
            />
```

Comment: For now, in the year of 2020, this is the most acceptable and complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how this isn't accepted, this is great, thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set maxImageSize programmatically? I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: This was the only way I was able to make it work.

Answer (score 19):

I stumbled across this and then found an answer through trial and error. It seems that you can increase the size of the floating action button if you set both `layout:width` and `layout:height` to `match_parent` and wrap the floating action button in a FrameLayout (doesn't have to be, but makes sense since you're only wanting to set the size of the button).

Then set the FrameLayout width and height to whatever you desire.

I upvoted Grace Coder's answer because it certainly addresses the problem but I thought this method would be safer and possibly more desirable.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chronometer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        android:id="@+id/record_fab" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You can see the difference in this screenshot I took:

[image]

The top FAB uses my code/workaround, whereas the bottom FAB uses the standard (mostly unchangeable) dimensions.

Comment: Better solution if there are multiple FAB buttons and only one needs to be increased in size.

Comment: Works when you make the fab bigger than normal, however it won't resize the icon inside the fab if you make the fab smaller.

Comment: This solution produces visual artifacts on pre-Lollipop devices, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51913347/9316168) for details.

Answer (score 13):

Since Design Support Library 27.1.0 there is an official way to set custom FAB size: [`app:fabCustomSize` XML attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton#attr_FloatingActionButton_fabCustomSize) and corresponding [`setCustomSize` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton#setCustomSize(int)). For increasing icon size you can use `android:scaleType="center"` and larger drawable. **UPDATE:** `android:scaleType` is now [broken](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117486785), use `fab.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER)` instead.

Other proposed solutions have some drawbacks:

- [Redefining default FAB dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34562287/9316168) cannot be applied to single button and is essentially a hack (uses non-public API which is subject to change).
- [Wrapping FAB in FrameLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38801998/9316168) (or just setting FAB's `layout_width` and `layout_height` to desired size, which has the same effect) looks awfully on pre-Lollipop devices. **UPDATE:** Now on post-Lollipop too (see screenshots below).
- [Setting `scaleX` and `scaleY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637787/9316168) requires adjusting margins (because visual FAB size now does not match its layout size) and scales non-scalable parts: button border and (pre-Lollipop) shadow width.

[Sample layout](https://gist.github.com/gmk57/5e47497dd3958c57ac308d79663475f9) as rendered on API 19 (left) and API 21 (right):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

To resize icon inside FAB:

```
app:maxImageSize="100dp"
```

Whole example:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:fabCustomSize="100dp"
    app:maxImageSize="75dp" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just making a clarification to @GraceCoder 's answer that @Tim Castelijns noted well in a comment above

You should go to your res->values->dimensions.xml file

[image]

and change it to add

```
<dimen name="design_fab_size" tools:override="true">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_fab_content_size" tools:override="true">98dp</dimen>
```

**Attention:**
It is

**design_fab_size**

not

*design_fab_size_mini*

Answer (score 1):

```
<dimen name="design_fab_size_mini" tools:override="true">120dp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_fab_size_normal" tools:override="true">150dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Android P preview, having the FAB match its parent's size stopped working for me, as the icon stopped scaling in size, making it much too small and way off-center.

The easiest method I have found as a replacement is to place the FAB in a FrameLayout, set a fair margin on the FAB so the shadow is not cut off (I used 10dp), set both's sizes to `wrap_content`, and then add `scaleX` and `scaleY` to the FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleX="1.6"
    android:scaleY="1.6">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This works as expected, allows one to easily scale by specific amounts, and does not affect any other floating action buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can easily custom fab size, just add

```
        app:fabCustomSize="32dp"
```

like

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_main_unlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_unlock"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/margin_very_massive"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
```