# How to remove padding icon in FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to use `FloatingActionButton` with custom size and use bigger icon inside. 
how can remove padding inside icon in `FloatingActionButton`

**Code**

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bottom_logo"
app:backgroundTint="#97D5F3"
android:padding="0dp"
app:maxImageSize="36dp"
app:fabCustomSize="64dp"
app:elevation="12dp"
app:borderWidth="0dp"
app:layout_anchor="@id/homeBottomBar"/>
```

**edit1**

> app:maxImageSize  => increase inside icon size
>
> app:fabCustomSize => change fab size

**edit2**

`design_fab_content_size` no longer use in `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: Do you want to remove the space between the icon and fab circle

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/34562287/9408181

Comment: @ShripadJadhav yes

Comment: @RahulChokshi. add `<dimen name="design_fab_content_size" tools:override="true">48dp</dimen>` to `dimens.xml` but nothing change

Comment: @saman You have to adjust fabCustomSize and maxImageSize attributes so that it will remove the padding some extend, here is formula how they are calculating image padding  
this.imagePadding = (preferredSize - this.maxImageSize) / 2;

Comment: @Pritam. thank you but i check this before

Comment: @ShripadJadhav. according to this if `maxImageSize`  and `fabCustomSize ` equal padding must be 0 but with use same size icon still has padding.